# error C2663: 'std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert' : 3 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, insert, qualifiers

Consider the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {};

struct T
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, A> _map;
};

struct L
{
    std::shared_ptr<const T> _c;
};


class f {
    void oid (std::shared_ptr<L> l, std::string st, A a) {
        l->_c->_map.insert(std::make_pair(st,a));
    }
};
```

During compilation, it throws the following error:

> error C2663: 'std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert' : 3 overloads have no legal
>   conversion for 'this' pointer
>             with
>             [
>                 _Traits=std::tr1::_Umap_traits,std::equal_to>,std::allocator>,false>
>             ]

I tryed to remove the `const` from `std::shared_ptr<const T> _c;` (not that I think it matters), but it constructs some other errors...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the errors if you try to remove the `const` that *actually* matters a lot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to insert into an `unordered_map` that you have declared to be `const`, which is not allowed. Why is `_c` inside `L` a `shared_ptr<const T>`??? That effectively makes `_map` on the object managed by the shared pointer a constant object an you will not be able to modify it.

Comment: Whoops!  I made the same mistake due to a copy and paste, but I was overlooking the const!